# createuserwizard refuese to add users due to password

Tags: regex, asp.net-membership, web-config, validation

When working with the the createuserwizard control, I found 
it always showed a "select a different password" message (in the example InvalidPasswordErrorMessage="Parola trebuie sa contina minim 7 caractere." ) when I try to add a 
user. The passwordregularexpression property is empty by default, I also 
tried to change it to some simple form like .{7,}, but nothing works...
I know that by default the password must have at least 7 characters and one of them must be alphanumeric etc... but how do I loosen up the password strength?
I have tried with
minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
and also tryed changing passwordStrengthRegularExpression and PasswordRegularExpression

```
 <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard" runat="server" 
        OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser" 
        oncontinuebuttonclick="ContinueButton_Click" 
        EmailRegularExpression="^([\w-\.]+)@domain.com" 
        EmailRegularExpressionErrorMessage="Adresa de email trebuie sa fie numeutilizator@domain.com." 
        oncreatinguser="CreateUserWizard_CreatingUser" 
        ConfirmPasswordLabelText="Confirmarea parolei:" PasswordLabelText="Parola:" 
        UserNameLabelText="Nume utilizator:" 
        ConfirmPasswordCompareErrorMessage="Parola si confirmarea parolei trebuie sa coincida." 
        DuplicateEmailErrorMessage="Adresa de email introdusa este deja folosita. Va rugam introduceti alta adresa de email." 
        InvalidEmailErrorMessage="Va rugam introduceti o adresa de email valida." 
        InvalidPasswordErrorMessage="Parola trebuie sa contina minim 7 caractere." 
        PasswordRegularExpression=".{7,}" 
        PasswordRegularExpressionErrorMessage="Parola trebuie sa contina minim 7 caractere." 
        PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Parola este obligatorie." 
        UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Introducerea unui nume utilizator este obligatorie."
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        passwordStrengthRegularExpression=".{7,}"
        LoginCreatedUser="false" DisableCreatedUser="true"          
        MailDefinition-BodyFileName="/signupmail.txt" OnSendingMail="CreateUserWizard1_OnSendingMail" MailDefinition-Subject="Activate cont rotaract.ro" MailDefinition-IsBodyHtml="True">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
         <StartNavigationTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Next" />
        </StartNavigationTemplate>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for / add a section like this in your `web.config` within the `<system.web>` section:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="FrontEndMembers">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="FrontEndMembers" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyDatabaseName" applicationName="/Website" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Emphasis on the `minRequiredPasswordLength` attribute